# How HashGraph Gossip Protocol Works?

Tags: distributed-computing, gossip, hashgraph, hedera-hashgraph

I read HashGraph paper https://www.swirlds.com/downloads/SWIRLDS-TR-2016-01.pdf and view "The HashGraph Protocol" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BAfsN3NW2Zg&list=PLr-BND1DE3sUR7GMm4lgw3B3D94OT4NuL&index=8&t=774s which explains how hashgraph works but it still not very clear to me how the Gossip protocol works.

Can someone give me a detailed exampled of how it works.

More specific when i sync with someone what my message contains, what does the other node inserts in his graph, how i learn what is inserted and then how the execution proceeds?

For example when i receive a transaction from a client i create a node which contains that transaction, insert it in the graph (in my row) and give it the current time as timestamp.Then how i proceed?

Answer (score 0):

To clarify, a gossip protocol isn't novel to hashgraph but commonly found across many distributed systems. What you're asking about is the 'gossip sync' between nodes. Hedera docs touch on this here, which you may find helpful -

https://docs.hedera.com/guides/core-concepts/hashgraph-consensus-algorithms/gossip-about-gossip

What hashgraph introduces is gossip about gossip – adding an additional hash of information to each event about how the gossip was first received by the gossiping node – and virtual voting.

Comment: When linking to your own site or content (or content that you are affiliated with), you [must disclose your affiliation _in the answer_](/help/promotion) in order for it not to be considered spam. Having the same text in your username as the URL or mentioning it in your profile is not considered sufficient disclosure under Stack Exchange policy.